# Google Sheets - filter multiple columns if contains text

Tags: google-sheets, filter, spreadsheet

I want to filter rows that contain a word in any column (among other text, not an exact match).

E.G.: I'd like to filter any line where the word "blue" appears in any column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

`=QUERY((BYROW(A2:C, LAMBDA(acx,IF(REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN("|",1,INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(acx," ","|"))),"blue"),acx,)))),"Select * Where Col1!=''")`

-

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow. How can I use this in a filter view, so only lines that contain the word "blue" would be visible?

Comment: so you wish to use the 'Filter by condition' option in column headers?!

Comment: Yes, but the word I'm looking for could be in any column.

Comment: Basically, I have a huge sheet and need to filter rows that contain a word (among other text) in any column

Comment: for the above sample data - within the Filter by condition>custom formula you can enter =OR(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"blue"), REGEXMATCH(B:B,"blue"), REGEXMATCH(C:C,"blue")) This would work but again if you have umpteen columns it would be a really long formula. anyways hoping someone else would pitch in with any short workarounds or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it should work with as many column as you have. Let me know!

```
=FILTER(A:C,BYROW(A:C,LAMBDA(each, REGEXMATCH (CONCATENATE(each),"blue"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER()` with `MMULT()` may work. Try-

```
=FILTER(A2:C7,MMULT(INDEX(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E1,A2:C7))),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:C7),1,1,0)))
```

You can use `E1` as filtering criteria. So make `E1` a dropdown and select your desired word on `E1` to filter from any column.

You can simplify above formula by using `BYROW()`. Try-

```
=FILTER(A2:C7,BYROW(A2:C7,LAMBDA(x,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E1,JOIN("|",x))))))
```

[image]